# PDF Files store

Tags: database, filesystems

I would like to know what is the better way to store files.

I develop a web application that generates PDF files. When the user clicks the 'save' button, I want to save those files permanently.

It's better to save those files in database or in files system?
Is there any framework for file storing?

Thanks.

Comment: Without any additional considerations in the question, a file system is generally a good place to store files.  It's optimized specifically for that.

Comment: Even when it's large amount a files?

Comment: Define "large amount of files."  File systems are designed to efficiently store files.  Unless there's a compelling reason not to use one, it seems to make sense.